# macro with variable arguments of different types

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to create macros to make is simple to create small instances of a custom tree-type. For this I'd like to specify children either as nodes or integers (without explicitly turning them into a `Node` type). [My attempt](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5ab07de6ce77a05d2047e45d971e6070&version=stable&backtrace=0) is below, which fails as the type of `$x` resolves as `MDTree`, with the message `expected enum MDTree, found integral variable`.

```
pub struct MultiNode {
    children: Vec<MDTree>
}
impl MultiNode {
    pub fn new(children: Vec<MDTree>) -> Box<MultiNode> {
        return Box::new(MultiNode { children: children });
    }
}
pub enum MDTree {
    Single(u32),
    Prime(Box<MultiNode>),
    Degenerate(Box<MultiNode>),
}
macro_rules! mod_single {
    ($x:expr) => { MDTree::Single($x) }
}
macro_rules! mod_multi {
    ($($x:expr),*) => {{
        let mut children: Vec<MDTree> = Vec::new();
        $(
            match $x {
                0...4294967295 => { children.push(mod_single!($x)); }
                _ => { children.push($x); }
            }
        )*
        MultiNode::new(children)
    }}
}
macro_rules! mod_prime {
    ($($x:expr),*) => { MDTree::Prime(mod_multi!($($x),*)) }
}
macro_rules! mod_degen {
    ($($x:expr),*) => { MDTree::Degenerate(mod_multi!($($x),*)) }
}
fn main() {
    let md: MDTree = mod_prime!(0, mod_degen!(1,2));
}
```

Is there any way to fix this without having to write `mod_prime!(mod_single(0), mod_degen!(mod_single(1),mod_single(2)))` or similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A macro cannot reason about the type of its operands, because macro expansion happens before type resolution.

That doesn't mean there's no solution, though! Indeed, the macro can expand to code whose behavior varies based on the expression's type. How do we do that? With traits, of course! We'll use the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html) and [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html) traits from the standard library here, but you can define your own trait if you prefer.

Let's first see how the `mod_multi!` macro looks like when using traits:

```
macro_rules! mod_multi {
    ($($x:expr),*) => {{
        let mut children: Vec<MDTree> = Vec::new();
        $(
            children.push($x.into());
        )*
        MultiNode::new(children)
    }}
}
```

The key point here is that the macro doesn't try to figure out the type of `$x`; it'll be figured out later on by the compiler, and the compiler will dispatch the call to `into()` based on that type. That does mean that if you pass an unsupported argument to the macro, you'll get compiler errors that might be unclear at first sight.

Now, we need to implement `Into` in order for both `u32` and `MDTree` to be accepted by the macro. `Into` has a blanket implementation based on the `From` trait, so we should implement `From` instead of `Into`. The standard library already provides `impl<T> From<T> for T`, so we can already pass an `MDTree` to the macro. That just leaves `u32`. The implementation goes like this:

```
impl From<u32> for MDTree {
    fn from(value: u32) -> MDTree {
        mod_single!(value)
    }
}
```

And now the macro invocation works as intended!

Answer (score 7):

While [the answer by Francis Gagné](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094083/3347227) may be more directly an answer to the question you asked, I just want to highlight the fact that macros also let you build trees like these with quite minimal syntax if you so desire (since you are after all asking about building trees with macros):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MDTree {
    Single(u32),
    Prime(Vec<MDTree>),
    Degenerate(Vec<MDTree>),
}

macro_rules! mdtree {
    ([$($sub:tt),*]) => {{
        MDTree::Prime(vec!($(mdtree!($sub),)*))
    }};
    ({$($sub:tt),*}) => {{
        MDTree::Degenerate(vec!($(mdtree!($sub),)*))
    }};
    ($e:expr) => {
        MDTree::Single($e)
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", mdtree!([1, [2, 3], {4, 5}]));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Apub%20enum%20MDTree%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Single(u32)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Prime(Vec%3CMDTree%3E)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Degenerate(Vec%3CMDTree%3E)%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Amacro_rules!%20mdtree%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%5B%24(%24sub%3Att)%2C*%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20MDTree%3A%3APrime(vec!(%24(mdtree!(%24sub)%2C)*))%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(%7B%24(%24sub%3Att)%2C*%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20MDTree%3A%3ADegenerate(vec!(%24(mdtree!(%24sub)%2C)*))%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(%24e%3Aexpr)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20MDTree%3A%3ASingle(%24e)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20mdtree!(%5B1%2C%20%5B2%2C%203%5D%2C%20%7B4%2C%205%7D%5D))%3B%0A%7D&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

You can use `(`, `{` and `[` as different variants, but beyond two using some actual identifiers are probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: Very neat - much more compact and less macro clutter. And for more node types / improved readability you can always add characters as part of the pattern, like `mdtree!([1, P[2, 3], D[4, 5])` ...

Comment: Actually, adding `P[2,3]` and `D[4,5]` doesn't seem to work - I'm guessing that's because they don't form a single token tree?

Comment: Yes, so you have to do `[P 2, 3]` `[D 4, 5]` if you want to add identifiers as far as I can tell.